# How can I sort the lines in a text file, by certain character after a question mark, in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

i have a lot of quizzes in a text file in the form :

- Which member of the Big Band era had the hit song 'Pennsylvania 6-5000'? Glenn Miller
- Who created the 201.5-meter long and 1.5-meter wide watercolor painting of 5000 carp ? Hai Shuet Yeung
- Who wrote the book '5000 Years of UFO's - Are We Really Alone ? Jim Hickman
- This dog has a sebaceous cyst on her belly. You advise the owner to ___ ? leave it alone
- This dog is showing all the classic symptoms of lungworm. He is most likely to have been snacking on ___ ? snails
- This dog has inflamed, bleeding gums. It is most likely he has ___ ? gum disease

I want to sort those lines according to "The first letter of the answer" e.g. all the questions with the answer starting with the letter G will be under each other like

- Which member of the Big Band era had the hit song 'Pennsylvania 6-5000'? Glenn Miller
- This dog has inflamed, bleeding gums. It is most likely he has ___ ? gum disease

and so on

how could I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a 3-step process to do this.

1. Do a search and replace by regular expression, replacing `^(.*)\?(.*)$` with `\2?\1`.
2. Sort it. You can Select All (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) and then use TextFX → TextFX Tools → Sort lines case insensitive (at column).
3. Perform step 1 again.

Basically, this just swaps the question and the answer, then sorts by the first character. Finally it swaps them back.

Comment: unfortunately didn't work with "Replace All" only for a single line and only for one time if i do it again it just mess them up rondomly

Comment: It works for me. Can you confirm that your replace box looks [like this](http://i.imgur.com/96kmDG6.png)? It's imperative that you have (a) *Wrap around* ticked, (b) *In selection* unticked, (c) *Search Mode* set to *Regular expression* and (d) *. matches newline* unticked.

Comment: @user327207 forgot the ping sorry

Comment: Hint: If the TextFX plugin is not available you can use `Edit - Line Operations - Sort Lines Lexicographically Ascending` for the sorting part.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any such function in notepad++.
However, if you are on linux, this shell cmd does the job.

```
sort -t'?' -f -k2 quiz.txt > output.txt
```

output.txt:

```
Which member of the Big Band era had the hit song 'Pennsylvania 6-5000'? Glenn Miller
This dog has inflamed, bleeding gums. It is most likely he has _ ? gum disease
Who created the 201.5-meter long and 1.5-meter wide watercolor painting of 5000 carp ? Hai Shuet Yeung
Who wrote the book '5000 Years of UFO's - Are We Really Alone ? Jim Hickman
This dog has a sebaceous cyst on her belly. You advise the owner to _ ? leave it alone
This dog is showing all the classic symptoms of lungworm. He is most likely to have been snacking on _ ? snails
```